# #Bootstrap/ I want to put col-md-3 at left and col-md-9 at right but failed

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, col

this is my code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel-primary">
    ............
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8" style="background:#000; color:#fff;">main</div>
</div>
```

and it shows

[image]

It always showed col-md-3 on the top and col-md-9 at bottom and couldn't show col-md-3 at left and cold-md-9 at right...

I tried col-md-push and col-md-pull and it worked, however i want to know why my original code didn't work and anyother (easy) ways to fix it.

by the way,this code worked

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8" style="background:#000; color:#fff;">main</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel-primary">
    ............
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

why???

Comment: Do you have any css that is breaking the bootstrap code?

Comment: i added panel-primary in col-md-9 and put border, just these~

Comment: i found my bug finally,thank u!

Answer (score 0):

It may have some margin by default check in **inspect element**

Or try class pull-left , pull-right

Comment: i found my bug, i missed a </div> before col-md-9.

Comment: If my answer helps check  as approved